# What am I doing wrong? (php: connecting to database with mysqli)

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to verify if I have connected to a database however whenever I check if the connection fails with an incorrect password, i get no response back on the page

```
<?php

include 'SETTINGS.php';

$RESPONSE = ["mode" => "response", "data" => ["title" => $NETWORKDISPLAYNAME, "message" => "Internal Error (0)"]];
$INPUTS = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

if(is_array($INPUTS))
{
    $SQL = mysqli_connect($SQLHOST, $SQLUSER, $SQLPASS, $SQLDB);

    if(!$SQL)
    {
        echo 'not connected';
    }

    else echo "connected";
}

else 
{
    $RESPONSE['data']['message'] = "Internal Error (1)";
}
die(create_response($RESPONSE['mode'],$RESPONSE['data']));

?>
```

when I deliberately use an incorrect password for the database I get no output on the page whatsoever

Comment: Enable php error reporting

Answer (score 1):

add this lines at the start of your code

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: thank you, i can now see that php is giving an error, how can i handle this error though? i dont want my code to not execute if the wrong password is given

Comment: @SamRoberts  try/catch can be used to trap errors. But why would this ever be a problem in this specific case? Surely your database password is pre-set in your settings code?